# javafx 2.0 adding border to Label

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx-2

I have a label with style class "test" in my javafx application.
I wanted to add white border around this label, so in the css file I tried:

```
-fx-border-width: 2;
-fx-border-color: white;
```

but that didnt worked so then i tried to add:

```
-fx-border-style: solid;
```

but that didnt worked either, following javafx css reference I didn't find anything useful.
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a jlabel? have you tried  setContentType("text/html");

Comment: no, as the title suggest i am using javafx ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can you try:

```
System.out.println(label);
```

it should print something like

```
Label@1858c80c[styleClass=label]
```

Is your css class printing too after styleClass=label ... ?
Or can you remove css class of the label and try setting the label style in code directly by:

```
label.setStyle("-fx-border-color: white;");
```

if you can see the changes then maybe you are unintentionally overriding css class definiton in css file. Check it.

Comment: as you suggested - using the label.setStyle("-fx-border-color: white;"); directly shows the border, BUT in the css i am using -fx-text-fill: blue; and it affecting the label forecolor so why don't the border on the same css selector affect the label too?

Comment: It should be affected. Are you editing the right css file. Try to clean and rebuild the app. Try to change foreground of the label to a different color other than blue to check if the label is taking correct css file and class.

Comment: cleaning and building the app worked! what an awful waste of time, thank you very much for all your help!